# FPGA (Verilog) - Working in simulation but not working on FPGA

Tags: verilog, fpga

The following code implements (or should implement) a 7 segment driver that reads a value from some switches and shows that value in the 4 7 segment displays.
The simulation works fine, but when it runs in the FPGA the 7 segment displays show something for a fraction of time and then no segment lights up.
I have no idea why it doesn't work.
Also, I implemented a simple counter. When I had "<=" inside of the always blocks it worked and when I had "=" it didn't, but in simulation it worked with both. The difference between "<=" and "=" is just that "<=" runs in parallel and "=" in sequence?

I should also say that it works if instead of sending the value from the switches to the display module I send a constant value.

display.v:

```
module display(
    input [15:0] count,
    output reg [6:0] seg,
    output dp,
    output [3:0] an,
    input clk
    );

reg [3:0] an_temp;
reg [6:0] rom [9:0];

initial
begin
    an_temp <= 1;
    rom[0] <= 'b1000000;
    rom[1] <= 'b1111001;
    rom[2] <= 'b0100100;
    rom[3] <= 'b0110000;
    rom[4] <= 'b0011001;
    rom[5] <= 'b0010010;
    rom[6] <= 'b0000010;
    rom[7] <= 'b1111000;
    rom[8] <= 'b0000000;
    rom[9] <= 'b0110000;
end

assign dp = 1;
assign an = ~an_temp;

wire [3:0] disp [3:0];

assign disp[0] = count % 10;
assign disp[1] = ((count - disp[0])/10) % 10;
assign disp[2] = ((count - disp[1]*10 - disp[0])/100) % 10;
assign disp[3] = ((count - disp[2]*100 - disp[1]*10 - disp[0])/1000) % 10;

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
    if (an_temp == 'b1000) an_temp = 1;
    else an_temp = an_temp = 1;
    case (an_temp)
        'b0001: seg <= rom[disp[0]];
        'b0010: seg <= rom[disp[1]];
        'b0100: seg <= rom[disp[2]];
        'b1000: seg <= rom[disp[3]];
        default: seg <= 'b1111111;
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

disp_clk.v:

```
module disp_clk(
    input clk,
    output disp_clk
    );

reg [31:0] count;

initial count = 0;

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
    count = count + 1;
    if (count == 400000) count = 0;
end

assign disp_clk = (count > 200000) ? 1 : 0;

endmodule
```

top.v:

```
module top(
    input clk,
    input [15:0] sw,
    output [6:0] seg,
    output dp,
    output [3:0] an
    );

wire disp_clk;

disp_clk disp_clk0(
    .clk(clk),
    .disp_clk(disp_clk)
    );

display disp0(
    .count(sw),
    .seg(seg),
    .dp(dp),
    .an(an),
    .clk(disp_clk)
    );

endmodule
```

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, somehow it appeared that way after copying. The correct is:
else an_temp = an_temp << 1;

Comment: This works if I replace sw by some constant on the top module.

Comment: Where do you change the value of the an_temp, for me, it looks like you always have an_temp=1 and you always show "'b0001: seg <= rom[disp[0]];"

Comment: It's right above the switch block. Look the previous comments.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I should also say that it works if instead of sending the value from
>   the switches to the display module I send a constant value.

Sounds like you are not meeting your timing window. If count is a constant vector, then the `disp` assignments should all be precomputed in synthesis. Otherwise, they need to be computed on the fly, and the requisite logic is inferred (which is rather slow).

`((count - disp[2]*100 - disp[1]*10 - disp[0])/1000) % 10` has a multiplier feeding into a division feeding into another division. One would hope that this is being inferred as cascading DSPs, but you should check your resource report to make sure, and as an added sanity check make sure the resource count for constant vs switched signaling shows a difference.

You may need to pipeline these operations if you cannot think of more optimal logic.

> The difference between "<=" and "=" is just that "<=" runs in parallel and "=" in sequence?

Yes, in a sense. `<=` and `=` refer to **non-blocking** and **blocking** assignments respectively.

The simulator will compute logic assignment on every time step.

For **non-blocking**, the right hand side is computed and may be updated later in the time step if it is logically dependent on other signaling, then just before the next time step begins, the left hand side of all the non-blocking assignments are assigned to the updated right hand side.

In a **blocking** assignment, the simulator will evaluate the right hand side and immediately assign it to the left hand side, in this way other logic is *blocked* from altering the assignment.

You can consider this sequential, but keep in mind that the sequentiality is only true *within* a functional block. If you have two always blocks that perform co-dependent evaluations on the same time step, you are not guaranteed which block the simulator will evaluate first and you might see some bizarre behavior based on how the simulator does it's scheduling.

Best practice is to use blocking assignments for behaviors that are intended to be combinatorial (i.e. `always@(*)`), and non-blocking assignments for those that are intended to be sequential (i.e. `always@(posedge Clock)`).

Comment: Thank you! I tried to reduce the clock frequency for the display to see if the problem persists. I reduced to a period of a second, so that I can see what is happening.
The first and the third segment displays are on more time than the other 2 displays. The other 2 displays are on just for a small instant. Why is this happening? If it was because of timing issues, then it wouldn't happen with a so slow clock.

Comment: When I increase the speed of the clock to the regular frequency just the first and the third segments turn on. This is confirmed with a slow clock, the first and the third segments are on most of the time and the other 2 are on just instantly.

Comment: It could be an issue with how your ring counter is synthesizing. Try replacing this code:


`if (an_temp == 'b1000) an_temp = 1;` 

`else an_temp = an_temp = 1;`

with this:

`an_temp <= {an_temp[2:0],an_temp[3]};`

this is simpler code, and more directly describes the ring oscillation behavior you want.

Comment: Now it is more close to what it should be! I reduced the display clock to 1 Hz so that I can see what is going on. Each display is lighted sequentially, as wanted, but during the sequence some of the other displays that are not currently on light just for instants. May it be because of the blocking assignements?

Comment: I've tested now with the 250 Hz clock and it works very well! Thank you.
But... What is the reason for not working with my code? It is equivalent in the result it produces and the simulation shows it should work...

Comment: There are caveats in RTL design that are important to understand. First, functional verification (that is where you use a simulator to verify that your behavior matches spec) is not the same thing as board level verification; the simulator is mapping RTL to a library of behavioral models, but a programmed board will have physical, electrical behavior that will differ from the model. The vendor synthesis tool will also change the behavior of you design, because it takes the behavior and maps it to structural elements which may not be logically equivalent to the behavior in all cases.

Comment: You cannot say that just because something has been verified in simulation, it will behave correctly on the board. Functional verification is just one step in the process of proving a design, and at the end of the day, if your design doesn't perform on the board, then it is an incorrect design.

Comment: Second, just because the behaviors are functionally equivalent based on your stimulus, does not mean they are functionally equivalent in all cases, nor does it mean they will infer the same hardware. The code snippet I gave you is not functionally equivalent to the one you had. Why? Because in the snippet of `an_temp` is initialized to something that is not 1-hot, it will never resolve itself to 1. Your code has some added return to 1 logic. I have a hunch that the blocking assignment you were using was causing the trouble, so you can try your code using non-blocking assignment and see.

Comment: As far as the glitching output goes, I'm not sure. I would probably need a deeper look at your project and the reports. Since I'm going off of hunches, I would think that your `disp` assignment logic is causing glitching. My original answer highlighted a very expensive line of code that I would think about reworking. What you are trying to implement is a binary to binary-coded-decimal (bcd) converter. There are many examples of binary-to-bcd converters that use a well known shifting algorithm, instead of compute logic like multiplication and division and I would try using that instead.

Comment: I've used the shifting algorithm for the binary to bcd converter and the problem persisted. I realized that the problem was in the initialization of the vector an (or an_temp). And this brings one question: is the initial block synthesizable? I replaced the initial block with a dedicated reset input and the problem disappeared.